# Hot to plot 3d vectors over time in Plotly

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to visualize 3D vectors in Jupyter. The vector values depend on time so I am trying to have a slider or other widget to act as a time selector. Here is a sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math


num_steps = 10
time_range = list(index / (num_steps - 1) for index in range(0, num_steps))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=time_range,
    data={
        "gravity": [np.array((t, 0.0, math.sqrt(1 - t**2))) for t in time_range],
    }
)
```

I'm using Plotly and following [their documentation](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/) on how to add sliders:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode


init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

fig = go.Figure()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    gravity = row["gravity"]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=[0.0, gravity[0]],
            y=[0.0, gravity[1]],
            z=[0.0, gravity[2]],
            mode='lines',
            visible=False,
        )
    )

fig.data[0].visible = True

steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[
            {"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
            {"title": "Slider switched to step: " + str(i)},
        ],
    )
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Time: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders,
    scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict(nticks=4, range=[-2,2],),
        yaxis = dict(nticks=4, range=[-2,2],),
        zaxis = dict(nticks=4, range=[-2,2],),
        aspectmode='manual',
        aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=1),
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

This works to some extend but I faced two issues:

- <s>Before moving the slider the first time, all the traces are rendered simultaneously.</s> Edit: Thanks to the comment by @r-beginners this issue is fixed.
- When increasing `num_steps` e.g. to `1000`, things start to get very slow and sluggish.

Is there a more light-weight way of doing this using Plotly? If not, are there other libraries that could do the job in Jupyter environments?

[image: t=0]
[image: t=4]

Comment: The first issue is that the first way to avoid displaying the entire graph is to set it to hidden when drawing the graph; `go.Scatter3d(...,mode='lines', visible=False)` the second issue is that there is always a performance loss due to the amount of data, so the only way to reduce the weight is to thin out the data or otherwise reduce the weight.

Comment: Thank you @r-beginners, fixed the first issue.